# Data sheet says 14 bit output, I am getting 16

Tags: i2c, stm32cubeide

I am doing a project on Cube IDE using a Nucleo board and a  magnetometer. In the data sheet for the magnetometer I can either have a 12 bit output or 14 bit output. I have set it up so I get 14 bits but when I look at data in the variables in my code they have 16 bits of data. I can't find anything online and I don't know if the outputs I am getting are incorrect because of this.
The magnetometer I am using is called BM1422AGMV.

[image: image of the code i am using to communicate with the magnetometer]

[image: picture of my data]

Answer (score 3):

The numbers that have 12 or 14 bits of range are sent as 16 bit signed integers from the chip.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: @ElliotWalster It means your code and value you get is absolutely correct. The chip sends -586 then that is what it sends to you.